# References Mutability in Java summing two vectors

Tags: java, arrays, mutability

I am new to Java and I am following a class, however in one of the exercises I came up with a doubt when comparing my answer vs. teacher.

Say I have a class that holds as attributes the coefficients of a polynomial and I now want to add two polynomials.

In the teacher solution (method add_1) he makes a copy of the coefficients of both arrays being summed, however from what I understood so far Doubles are immutable, so I assume I don´t need to use a copy, but only address directly (method add_2). I have tested an my values in the array are not mutated, however I wanted to confirm my understanding.

```
public class Polynomial {

    // coefficient at index k belongs to term x^k
    // consistency: array is always present and contains at least one number (which
    // may be zero)
    private double[] coefficients;

    // --------------------- constructors
    // ----------------------------------------------

    // constructor: zero polynomial
    public Polynomial() {
        coefficients = new double[1];
        coefficients[0] = 0;
    }

    public static Polynomial add_1(Polynomial f, Polynomial g) {        // Option 1
        double[] f_array = f.getCoefficients();//Do I need this copy?
        double[] g_array = f.getCoefficients();//Do I need this copy?
        int n = Math.max(f_array.length, g_array.length); // new array needs to be this long

        double[] target = new double[n];
        // fastest way to do it without if-statements:
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = 0;//Zero vector array
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < f_array.length; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = target[k] + f_array[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < g_array.length; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = target[k] + g_array[k];
        }

        // Turn array into an object
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial();
        p.setCoefficients(target);
        return p;
    }

    public static Polynomial add_2(Polynomial f, Polynomial g) {        // Option 2
        int n = Math.max(f_array.length, g_array.length); // new array needs to be this long

        double[] target = new double[n];
        // fastest way to do it without if-statements:
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = 0;//Zero vector array
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < f.coefficients.length; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = target[k] + f.coefficients[k];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < g.coefficients.length; k = k + 1) {
            target[k] = target[k] + g.coefficients[k];
        }

        // Turn array into an object
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial();
        p.setCoefficients(target);
        return p;
    }


    // --------------------- setter / getter methods
    // -----------------------------------

    // setter for coefficients, creates a copy(!) of coefficients and stores it
    public void setCoefficients(double[] coefficients) {
        this.coefficients = new double[coefficients.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < coefficients.length; k = k + 1) {
            this.coefficients[k] = coefficients[k];
        }
    }

    // getter for coefficients, returns a copy(!) of the polynomials coefficients
    public double[] getCoefficients() {
        double[] copy = new double[coefficients.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < coefficients.length; k = k + 1) {
            copy[k] = coefficients[k];
        }
        return copy;
    }

}
```

1. Is my method add_2 protected against mutation or is there any reason I should use a copy?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `double[] f_array = f.getCoefficients();//Do I need this copy?`

This belies a misunderstanding of java.

`f.getCoefficients()` doesn't return a double array. That is impossible; java can only return primitives and references. It returns **a reference to** a double array.

No copy of an array is being made here. The only copies java makes implicitly are of references and primitives; any other copying is something you'd have to do explicitly using e.g. a `copy()` or `clone()` or `Arrays.copyOf` invocation. All that you've done here is make a copy of **the reference** which doesn't matter. `f.getCoefficients()` already returns a copy of the reference.

Let me try to explain with an example:

```
class Example {
    double[] array = new double[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        double[] arr = ex.array;
        arr[0] = 1;
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(ex.array[0]);
        ex.array[0] = 2;
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(ex.array[0]);
        arr = new double[20];
        arr[0] = 20;
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(ex.array[0]);
    }
}

> 1
> 1
> 2
> 2
> 20
> 2
```

Initially there is only one array, and both `ex.array` and `arr` are references pointing to this array. `arr[0] =` is dereferencing the reference and doing an operation on what you find there, thus, whilst `arr` and `ex.array` are copies, it's a copy of the same reference, and just like if I make a copy of a treasure map and hand it to you, if you then follow your map, dig down, and steal the treasure, and then later I follow my copy, I find the treasure gone - so it is here: `arr[0] = 1` affects the one and only array, and thus printing `ex.array[0[]` also shows `1`.

Later, with `arr = new double[20]` we first make a new object (`new double[20]`) and then assign a reference to this newly created object to `arr`, which has no effect on `ex.array`. Thus, *now*, it's like you have a treasure map to a completely different treasure vs. my `ex.array` treasure map. Therefore, when you follow your map, dig down, and put a `20` in the box, if I follow my map, I **do not** see that, hence why the last 2 lines prints `20` and `1`, and not `20` and `20`.

Comment: Many thanks for the mind blowing explanation and clear example, just a remark I tested and the printing values were 1,1,2,2,20,2. What makes sense, given that ex and arr have the same reference. Now I believe that the more important step concerning the two different functions (add_1 and add_2) would be actually the allocation of memory to the double[] target = new double[n]; and then copying this reference to the p.setCoefficients(target).  So from my understanding, in this specific example I do not actually need the step f.getCoefficients(), would you agree?

Comment: _1, 1, 2, 2, 20, 2_ - yep, typo. Answer fixed.

Comment: There is indeed no point whatsoever to copying the coefficients, here.